# Stationary dependent variable, integrated regressor: what to do?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, cointegration, unit-root

Im running a univariate regression and the Y variable doesnt have a unit root, but the X does. The regression is:

`ExcessReturn_t = alpha + beta * (Dividend yield)_t-1 + e`

After running ADF on both of them, the DY has an unit root, but the excess return does not. How do I proceed to transform them? Do I need to take the Delta of Y too, or only of the X?

For my regression I am using the lagged DY. Can I continue to cointegration, error correction model and forecasting by using the lagged DY?

Im a beginner in this so can someone explain this to me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us write your model in a parsimonious notation,
$$
y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t,
$$
where $y_t$ is the excess return and $x_t$ is the dividend yield. Since $y_t$ is stationary while $x_t$ is integrated, the two diverge, and the model does not make sense. To fix the problem, you may use $\Delta x_{t-1}$ in place of $x_{t-1}$. There is no point in differencing a stationary variable (and it is not innocuous, hence the notion of overdifferencing), so $y_t$ should remain as is. There is no room for considering cointegration as only one of the original variables is integrated while the other is stationary. You could investigate cointegration if you took the cumulative sum of $y_t$ in place of the raw $y_t$, though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Richard! Much appreciated!
One last detail. R is supposed to be regressed on log(DY). Do I run the ADF test on DY or log(DY)?
When I do the Delta(X_t-1), do I do Delta(logDY) or log(Delta(DY))?

Comment: You run the ADF test on the variable that will be in the regression, so $\log(\Delta y)$. You do $\Delta\log(y)$ since this approximates the percentage change in $y$. (You cannot do $\log(\Delta y)$ for a purely technical reason as well -- because you cannot take logs of negative values.)